# What is V8 cache size on disk and in memory

Tags: caching, browser-cache, chromium, v8

Every cache method has some upper limit of megabytes, until it starts to overwrite already taken memory. I need to know, what's the upper limit for V8 (hardware optimization, disk and in-memory usage would be awesome). I've tried to look around chromium source code but because of its size, I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding disk caches: V8 itself does not use any disk caches. Via its API, it allows the respective embedder (Chromium, Node, ...) to cache various things (strings and bytecode come to mind). The respective caching policies are up to the embedder; V8 does not know or care.

Regarding memory caches: V8 caches all sorts of things in all sorts of manners. Some caches have size limits, others use other mechanisms to avoid unbounded growth. Please specify what cache exactly you are interested in.

Comment: Specyfing - I am interested in the maximum size of all caches in peak, generated by V8 in Chromium.

Comment: "Tell me everything" is not specific.